# Conditional statements based on ajax function calls results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to display messages and call functions based on the ajax function results. In this case, the function sends a GET request and receives only one response: a string which is either "yes", "no" or error. I want to display a message when the response is " no" or "error" and call another function when the response is "yes"

when the response is yes, I want to call the function CheckCompanyProfile()

```
        function CheckDatabaseInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'CheckDatabase',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (res) {
                    DBResult(res);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    $('#message').html('Unknown error occured while connecting to the server');
                }
            });
        }


        function CheckCompanyProfile() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'CheckCompanyProfile',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (res) {

                    if (res === "found") {
                        // proceed to login
                        console.log(res);
                        window.location.replace("UserLogin");
                    } else if (res === "conflict") {
                        //resolve
                        console.log(res);
                        $('#message').html('There are conflicting company profiles. \n\
       Click <a href="#">here</a> to resolve');
                    } else {
                        //create profile
                        console.log("create profile");
                        $('#message').html('We could not find your company. \n\
       Click <a href="#">here</a> to create');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    //console.log('Error connecting to the server');
                    $('#message').html('Unknown error occurred while connecting to the server');
                }
            });
        }

        function DBResult(x) {
            const val = x;
            if (val === "yes") {
                console.log("good");
                $('#message').html('Database found');
            } else if (val === "no") {
                console.log("database bot found");
                $('#message').html('We could not find system database');
            } else {
                console.log("Something went wrong. Unknown error has been detected");
                $('#message').html('Something went wrong. Unknown error has been detected');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi. So what is your question? or what is the problem?

Comment: I want to display message or call a function based on the value of the success function result. If the result is "error" or "no", I display a message. If the result is "OK", I call a function.

Comment: So why arent you calling the function when the answer is yes?